# Como mostrar um elemento por alguns segundos e depois escondê-lo?

Tags: javascript, html

Tem como eu informar um `visible : true` por tempo? Quero que seja verdadeiro somente por alguns segundos depois volte para `false`.

Comment: Veja [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) e também faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer o funcionamento da comunidade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Serve assim?

```js
function esconde() {
  document.getElementById("exemplo").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
setTimeout(esconde, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="exemplo" style="visibility: visible">Vou sumir em 3 segundos</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/HiddenAfterTime.js).

[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: SIm entendi seu codigo. mas eu preciso que a imagem seja True por 3 segundos e o resntante false... Tem como?

Comment: É só inverter, você pode usar sua criatividade para ir adaptando e fazer coisas novas. Mas eu mudei na resposta especialmente pra você.

Comment: Agora a função `Mostra` esconde em vez de mostrar :P

Comment: @bfavaretto chato :P

Comment: Ser chato funciona :D