# Mostrar elemento e esconder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema de alerts onde a div onde fica os alerts está com diplay none , entao quando surge um novo alert no meu js faço um togle para aparecer esse alert na tela assim

```
       $("#alerts").toggle( "slow" );
```

como faço com que o alert fique somente 2 segundos na tela e depois desapareça

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar um `.delay( milisegundos )` entre os métodos encadeados:

```
$("#alerts").show("slow").delay(5000).hide("slow");
```

Veja funcionando no **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/EgVAxL)**.

- `show("slow")` mostra o elemento;
- `delay(5000)` aguarda 5 segundos (use 2000 para 2 segundos);
- `hide("slow")` esconde o elemento.

Pra quem não precisar do jQuery para outras coisas, aqui tem uma versão com JS puro:

> [Como mostrar um elemento por alguns segundos e depois escondê-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83309/70)

Comment: obrigado ajudou muito